# Loading Numeric data into BigQuery with Avro files created with goavro

Tags: go, google-bigquery, avro

I am trying to figure out how to load dollar values into a Numeric column in BigQuery using an Avro file. I am using golang and the [goavro](https://github.com/linkedin/goavro) package to generate the avro file.

It appears that the appropriate datatype in go to handle money is big.Rat.

BigQuery [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#decimal_logical_type) indicates it should be possible to use Avro for this.

I can see from a few [goavro test cases](https://github.com/linkedin/goavro/blob/05dc57f3d804f985f554fbd6da9011aac77da68e/logical_type_test.go#L82) that encoding a *big.Rat into a fixed.decimal type is possible.

I am using a goavro.OCFWriter to encode data using a simple avro schema as follows:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "MyData",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "ID",
      "type": [
        "string"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Cost",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "fixed",
          "size": 12,
          "logicalType": "decimal",
          "precision": 4,
          "scale": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am attempting to Append data with the "Cost" field as follows:

```
map[string]interface{}{"fixed.decimal": big.NewRat(617, 50)}
```

This is successfully encoded, but the resulting avro file fails to load into BigQuery:

```
Err: load Table MyTable Job: {Location: ""; Message: "Error while reading data, error message: The Apache Avro library failed to parse the header with the following error: Missing Json field \"name\": {\"logicalType\":\"decimal\",\"precision\":4,\"scale\":2,\"size\":12,\"type\":\"fixed\"}"; Reason: "invalid"}
```

So am doing something wrong here... Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I need to use bytes.decimal instead of fixed.decimal

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "MyData",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "ID",
      "type": [
        "string"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Cost",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "bytes",
          "logicalType": "decimal",
          "precision": 4,
          "scale": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then encode similarly

```
map[string]interface{}{"bytes.decimal": big.NewRat(617, 50)}
```

And it works nicely!